# print each single character on a new line of a single input word without using length funtion and array

Tags: c

I want to accept a **single word** and print each character of that single **input word on a new line**.

```
This is my input:Maria
    Output:M
           a
           r
           i
           a
```

**But here condition is I dont want to use Length function and nor any array.**

I have done this with length function but i am not getting how to do this without using length function and array too.

Could anybody help me with this ??

Comment: `nor any array.` please let us know how you're planning to store the `single word` otherwise.

Comment: I was ask to perform this task in 1 interview so.i am not getting it how do do this thats why i have ask on stack overflow

Comment: Downvoter please give me your reason for downvoting.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c !=EOF)
        printf("\t%c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
maria
    m
    a
    r
    i
    a
```

Comment: could you please explain me this line:while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c !=EOF)

Comment: Reads a character from the input buffer until we press `INTRO` or `EOF` (`CTRL+D` on Unix, `CTRL+Z` on Windows), all those charactes are printed at the end because `stdin` is line buffered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that without using length function

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() 
 { char s[1000],i;
   printf("Enter a string: "); 
   scanf("%s",s); 
   for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; ++i)
   {
    printf("%c",s[i]);
    printf("\n");
   } 
   return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: so shall we assume `char s[1000]` is not an array? ;-)